# Wordpress Custom post type permalinks resulting in 404 unless "post_type" query is appended -?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks, custom-taxonomy

I'm having a really hard time figuring this one out. I've got a custom WP theme with regular posts, and then an "article" post type. I've got permalinks working as intended with regular posts, and I am attempting a custom permalink structure for the "article" post type, using a custom "issue_tax" taxonomy.  The permalink is being rewritten as I intend, for example:

```
/spring-2015/article-name-here
```

but it results in a 404 no matter what I try. I've refreshed the permalink settings, flushed caches, etc.  The odd thing I just discovered is that this does work, with no 404:

```
/spring-2015/article-name-here/?post_type=article
```

Does anyone know why this might be happening? And if there is a way to have it work without the query appended?

Here's what I'm using to rewrite the permalink:

```
function ze_show_permalinks( $post_link, $id = 0 ){
    $article = get_post($id);
    if ( $article->post_type == 'article' ){
        $articleterms = wp_get_object_terms( $article->ID, 'issue_tax' );
        if( $articleterms ){
            return str_replace( '%issuedate%' , $articleterms[0]->slug , $post_link );
        }
    }
    return $post_link;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'ze_show_permalinks', 10, 2 );
```

Any help appreciated..!!

Comment: try to enable wp debug and see if there is any additional info in the debug.log

Comment: Hi yuyokk - interesting - I"m getting some errors about wp-includes/link-template.php: Trying to get property of non-object in /nas/wp/www/cluster-1244/tcumagazine/wp-includes/link-template.php on line 356 - also line 368 379 and 335, which all have to do with the page_link and _get_page_link functions...seems like it could be related, but I am over my head a bit with this...Although - the errors relate to page_link, not post_link, which is what I"m using...?

Comment: I suggest trying to fix this error and see if it helps.